# how to click "agree" button automatically while web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project on a website sreality.cz

it has dynamic content, so I needed to use selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Set up the Chrome driver (download the appropriate version)
driver = webdriver.Chrome

# Navigate to the URL
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.sreality.cz/en/search/for-sale/apartments/praha?page=1")

# Wait for the page to load 
time.sleep(10)

# click on the "Accept Cookies" button if it's there
try:
    cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-testid='button-agree']"))
    )
    cookies_button.click()
except:
    pass
```

`your text`

HOWEVER, I can't make it click accept cookies button automatically. Maybe I am referencing something wrong.. Please, check the attached image to see how the button code looks like on the page html itself.

p.s. sorry if my question is messy or unclear, it's my first project. Full project on:  tamarsdataportfolio.wordpress.com

I tried referencing that agree cookies button from the webpage html, but somehow it doesn't work.

[HTML of the website with agree button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV4IB.png)

Comment: `except: pass` is a **terrible** way to handle errors.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: I don’t know a better way 

Comment: Don't use try/except at all.  Just let the exception happen, so you can actually **see** the error.

Comment: i try to do this `by.XPATH` and it threw an error. like it is not visable